# how to set a key,value in a mongo array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of students where they can have other students as friends

```
{name:'someone', email:'st', friends[ObjectId,ObjectId]}
```

To access the list of friends I'll have to populate that object and search inside all the objects of the array friends
this will take mutch time

What I would like to do is this:

```
collection.find({name:'someone'},function(err,obj){
  if(obj['user1'])
    //do st
  else
    //do st
})
```

this will reuire that i insert objects like this:

```
collection.find({name:'st'},function(err,obj){
  obj.friends['some one']=ObjectId(of an other student)
})
```

but this last one is not working

Comment: `collection.find({name:'someone'}` is expecting to be a single student ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this if you use `Mongoose` in addition to `Mongo`. In your students schema you need an Array of friends which will be just the ID's of other students:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var StudentSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  friends: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

Then when adding a friend all you need to do is push the `ID` of that friend into the array of friends.

Once the collection stores the relationship properly you can use [`mongoose's populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)  method to actual fill in the data in your API end point.. Something like this:

```
app.get('/student/:id, function(req, res){
    Student.find({_id: req.params.id})
    .populate('friends')
    .exec(function(err, student){
    if(err){
     // handle error
    } else {
       res.json(student)
    }
   }) 

});
```